# SQLite Error: Cannot delete WhereListIterator`1: it has no PK

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, extension-methods

I'm trying to delete records from a database using SQLite/C# in Visual Studio 2012. Whenever I attempt to delete a record I get the following error:

> SQLite Error: Cannot delete WhereListIterator`1: it has no PK

I am wanting to delete records using two different methods. Either delete using only the EID, which is the primary key, or delete records where the user provides everything but the EID.

```
if (EID_TextBox.Text != String.Empty) {
    if (Roster_Enrollment.Any(x => x.EID.Equals(Int32.Parse(EID_TextBox.Text)))) {
        App.DBConnection.Delete(Roster_Enrollment.Where(x => x.EID.Equals(Int32.Parse(EID_TextBox.Text))));
        Message_TextBlock.Text = "Enrollment deleted.";
    } else
        Message_TextBlock.Text = "Enrollment not found.";
}
else if (Roster_Enrollment.Any(x => x.CourseNo.Equals(CourseNo_TextBox.Text) && x.SectionNo.Equals(SectionNo_TextBox.Text) && x.Tno.Equals(Tno_TextBox.Text)))
    App.DBConnection.Delete(Roster_Enrollment.Where(x => x.CourseNo.Equals(CourseNo_TextBox.Text) && x.SectionNo.Equals(SectionNo_TextBox.Text) && x.Tno.Equals(Tno_TextBox.Text)));
else
    Message_TextBlock.Text = "Enrollment not found.";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does your class data model have the `Table` attribute and `PrimaryKey` attribute?

```
[Table("StuffDataModel")]
public class StuffDataModel
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] Stuff { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Note that the primary key need's to have a *public setter*. This detail just cost me an hour of debugging.

Comment: I had set my key with [Key} which compiled and ran but still got the Sqlite error.  So I changed that to [Primary Key] and visual studio had me add using SQLite; and the delete worked.  Also I dropped the table and let my app recreate it. Not sure if that was required.

Answer (score 2):

I see were the problem is... The Delete method takes an object as argument but you are using a query in argument.
Try this instead:
App.dbconnection.Table().Delete(x => x.EID.Equals(Int32.Parse(EID_TextBox.Text)));